# Как получать нажатия стрелочек, с помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, ос

При нажатии стрелок вверх вниз, как мы все знаем, терминал возвращает историю ввода. Хотел бы сделать так же, только при нажатии стрелок вверх вниз в скрипте python выдает

`^[[A` или `^[[B`

Допустим вот сам небольшой скрипт

```py
import os


while True:
    a = input("$ ")
    os.system(a)
```

Хотел бы встроить в него историю, которую вызывал бы стрелками (как в терминале)

Comment: Хорошая идея. Начинай. Будут конкретные вопросы по конкретным проблемам - спрашивай.

Comment: Для этого вам нужно сделать на питоне эмулятор терминала. смотрите в сторону curses

Comment: [обёртка для gnu/readline](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap), от языка не зависит. ну или нативный [python-овский интерфейс к gnu/readline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html)